# How to break a long headed line in markdown pandoc?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

In this markdown code

```
## This a very long line header which was written in markdown
```

I'd like to split the long line in 2 lines but maintaining the style of header.

This is wrong intent:

```
## This a very long line header which 
was written in markdown
```

result in:

> ### This a very long line header which
>
> was written in markdown

The strategy to use 2 times ## doesn't work

[image: code]

result (unnecesary break line):

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

There's a [pandoc issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/82) requesting linebreaks in headers in the input markdown that don't show up in the output, but this is not possible in CommonMark either and won't be implemented in pandoc..

You can escape the newline with a backslash, however, this will insert a `<br>` tag there.

```
# This a very long line header which \
was written in markdown
```

If you're only targeting HTML output you can also just write raw HTML in markdown:

```
<h1>This a very long line header which
was written in markdown</h1>
```

Comment: The backslash is what I was looking for. I thought that might be the case but the confirmation is helpful