# Markdown how to spread out header source over several lines, while still rendering as one continuous header

Tags: markdown, newline, readme

I have a header 2 (`## h2`) that has a lot of text (over 80 characters).  I try to keep the lines within markdown files within 80 characters, and so by breaking up long lines.

**Goal**: wrap a long header line's text in the source, without affecting the rendering

With normal sentences, this is easy... the markdown properly renders as one continuous sentence:

```
This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
very very very very very very very very very very long line.
```

[image: normal text with a line wrap]

However, I can't figure out how to do this with headers.  If I make a second header line in the source, the markdown is rendered as two different lines of header 2.

```
## This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
## very very very very very very very very very very very long header.
```

[image: h2 with a line wrap]

**How can I make markdown line wrapping work like normal text, except for header 2?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of [How to break a long headed line in markdown pandoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266938/how-to-break-a-long-headed-line-in-markdown-pandoc) from 5 years ago

There is nothing in Markdown syntax about being able to break up lines -- see https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

There was some discussion about adding this capability to pandoc's markdown processor in https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/82 but ultimately the issue was closed without changing anything.

So in short the answer is no, you can't break up the header source over several lines in Markdown while still rendering as one continuous header.

Comment: You should vote to close duplicate questions, not answer them. Do not answer off topic and duplicate questions. [answer]

Comment: Thank you @Rob. I’ve read the page you linked to. Thank you for that reference and I’ll follow it going forward.   “ Users with 3000 reputation can cast up to 50 close votes per day. “. I dont have that much reputation yet — I suppose I should just comment then to indicate the duplicate?

Comment: Yes. Just comment.

Comment: Super, thank you very much, @Rob.

Comment: Thanks for this concise answer, much better than the question (just a comment).

Comment: You are very welcome, @hakre!  :)